# PHP Captcha: What is a "private key" and "public key"?

Tags: php, captcha

What is the difference between private key and public key and how is it used?

Comment: What does this have to do with captcha?

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://recaptcha.net/plugins/php/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)
You create a key-pair (public and private) the receivers public key is used to encrypt messages. The private key of the receiver is used to decrypt the this message.

Answer (score 0):

Normally private and public key are terms that belong to assymetric encryption algorithms. I don't see a connection to CAPTCHA or PHP5 in this special case.